# How to deploy a Power app (canvas app) to Teams App store and make it available for all Teams users?

Tags: microsoft-teams, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

Hello I am an intern and brand new to Microsoft developer environments. I want to make a Microsoft Power App (canvas app) be made available on the Teams App Store and available for any Teams app user. However tutorials I've been able to find so far include putting the custom app on Teams and making it available just for your local organization's Team which you are a part of.

I would like to find some tutorials or better resources that explain how to make a Microsoft Power app canvas app available on the Teams App store for all Teams users.

After doing some research I have found out to put the app on Teams I would need:

Azure App Service for computing resources.
Azure Storage OR Dataverse to store data.
Azure Active Directory for authentication and authorization.

But I still don't know exactly how to deploy it onto the Teams Store. Any resources, video tutorials or links to documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/publish#what-to-expect-after-you-submit-your-app

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the app available to all Teams users, you need to submit it for approval. This kind of distribution requires Microsoft approval. For more information on how to publish your app to the Teams store, see the [publish to the Teams store documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/publish).

Once your app is approved, it will be available in the Teams store. Users can find it in your organization's app store by going to "Built for Your Organization Name" on the Apps page. If you have created and assigned an app setup policy, the app will be pinned to the app bar in Teams for easy access for users who were assigned the policy.